# alias fo rm command ( cp comand issue )

Tags: linux, bash

I try to change the rm command into a command that give me backup of the file and remove the file after.

```
function move_to_trash () {
        unset rm;
        cp -v "$@" "/home/`whoami`/backup/" &&  rm "$@";
}


alias rm='move_to_trash'
```

Output:

```
'file1' -> '/home/dorchester/backup/file1'
'file1' -> '/home/dorchester/backup/file1'
'file1' -> '/home/dorchester/backup/file1'
'file1' -> '/home/dorchester/backup/file1'
'file1' -> '/home/dorchester/backup/file1'
'file1' -> '/home/dorchester/backup/file1'
'file1' -> '/home/dorchester/backup/file1'
'file1' -> '/home/dorchester/backup/file1'
```

The cp command keep running without starting rm "$@" command, which is something really strange. This seems to be a infinite loop, I would like to know how can this loop happen. Also, I'm aware of existence solution that turn cp command into move to trash command such rmtrash, though I prefer bash scripting method.

Comment: `unset rm` unsets a variable named `rm`. It doesn't affect aliases.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I added "command" prior to rm command. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Note: unset command doesn't remove aliases.

```
function move_to_trash () {
        cp -vr "$@" "/home/`whoami`/backup/" && command rm -rf "$@";
}

alias rm='move_to_trash'
```

This code work for me if I want to remove a file or directory.